# Dart radix sort implementation

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, radix-sort

how can i write the below code in dart

```
// js code

let digitBuckets = Array.from({length: 10}, () => []);

// dart code

List digitBuckets = List.from({});//confused here

// how can i write this: Array.from({length: 10}, () => []);
// in dart List digitBuckets = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused about what you want but I think you want to create a List of Lists which you can do like this:

```
void main() {
  final digitBuckets = List.generate(10, (_) => <dynamic>[]);
  print(digitBuckets); // [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
}
```

Note, the lists should be more specifically typed so you can get some type safety. But your questions does not contain any clue about what you want to use these lists for so I have used `dynamic` in my example.

Comment: i am trying to implement Radix sort in dart

Comment: here is the full issue https://github.com/wednesday-solutions/dart-algorithm-club/issues/1

Comment: Please update your question so it actually states your problem and what solution you want. Right now your title does not relate to your question.

Comment: void main() {
  final digitBuckets = List.generate(10, (_) => <dynamic>[]);
  print(digitBuckets); // [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
}